# Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I have some difficulties understanding the following:

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent random variables s.t.

$P[X_n=1]=1−P[X_n=0]=\frac{1}{n}$

After using the Borell Cantelli lemma, I could show that:

$P(\limsup [X_n=0])=1$

$P(\limsup [X_n=1])=1$

Now using the fact that $\operatorname{[\limsup F_n]}^c  = [\liminf \operatorname{(F_n)}^c]$ I concluded that

$P(\liminf [X_n=1])=0$

$P(\liminf [X_n=0])=0$         as $P(A)+P(A^C)=1$.

This implies that as $X_n$ is either $0$ or $1$, $\liminf X_n$ is never constant with probability $1$, contradicting some of the implications of the Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law.

Could someone please clarify this?
Much appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: You might be confusing limsups of random variables and limsups of events, please check the definitions. Also, Borel-Cantelli lemma does not give $P(\limsup X_n=0)=1$. Finally, please tag more appropriately.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer thanks a lot for that. I am relatively new to the site.

Comment: The divergence of the series you wrote implies that $X_n=0$ for infinitely many $n$, almost surely. Which does not mean that $\limsup X_n=0$ almost surely.

Comment: I thought that $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} P(X_n=0)=\infty$, and as the events $F_n = [X_n = 0]$ are independent one could use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma to imply that $P(lim sup X_n = 0) = 1$. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Can you please clarify the distinction between i.o. = infinitely often and lim sup? I thought that they can be interchanged, i.e. if an event, such as $[X_n=0]$ happens i.o then we can use lim sup. So if I want to compute $P(lim sup X_n = 0)$ and $P(lim inf X_n = 0)$ how do I do that? Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the events $A_n=[X_n=0]$. By definition, the event $\limsup A_n$ happens if and only if $A_n$ happens for infinitely many $n$, hence the general formula 
$$
\limsup A_n=\bigcap\limits_n\bigcup\limits_{k\geqslant n}A_k.
$$
In our case, consider $N=\{n\mid X_n=0\}$, then 
$$
\limsup A_n=[X_n=0\ \text{for infinitely many}\ n]=[N\ \text{is infinite}].
$$
Consider $Y=\liminf X_n$. This is a random variable $Y$ characterized by the fact that $Y=1$ if $X_n=1$ for every $n$ large enough, that is,
$$
[Y=1]=[\exists n,\ \forall k\geqslant n,\ X_k=1].
$$
and that $[Y=0]=[N\ \text{is infinite}]$.

Finally, **for $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables** $(X_n)$,
$$
\limsup[X_n=0]=[\liminf X_n=0].
$$
Likewise, again for $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables $(X_n)$,
$$
\liminf[X_n=0]=[(X_n)\ \text{converges and}\ \lim X_n=0]=[\limsup X_n=0],
$$
$$
\liminf[X_n=1]=[(X_n)\ \text{converges and}\ \lim X_n=1]=[\liminf X_n=1],
$$
and
$$
\limsup[X_n=1]=[X_n=1\ \text{for infinitely many}\ n]=[\limsup X_n=1].
$$